# Is there allows to make a procedure inside of other procedure in mysql5.7

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

When we create a procedure it can allows to call other procedure which is run in the server. But if there have a chance to create over one or more procedures inside of a procedure in mysql 5.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement inside a procedure body.

```
mysql> create procedure MyProc()
  begin 
    create procedure MyOtherProc() begin select 1; end; 
  end //

ERROR 1303 (2F003): Can't create a PROCEDURE from within another stored routine
```